# iphone ipa file on device with developer provisioning file - will it be deployed on device in a different MAC machine

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

I am a beginner in iOS development. I have got some understanding on provisioning profiles in IOS. Please help me confirm my understanding.

Here is my scenario. iOS application developed on MAC1 with developer certificate1 and built using developer provisioning profile1 which includes UDID1 is deployed on device D1 with UDID1 successfully.

I add a new device D2 with UDID2 to my developer provisioning profile1 and built the app in MAC1 and generated an .ipa file.

I have a new MAC machine M2 where i try to connect device D2 and try to deploy the app on device D2. I copied the latest developer provisioning profile to the device.

Questions
1. Will the provisioning profile get installed successfully ?
2. Will i be able to deploy the .ipa file on device only with the developer provisioning profile and without developer certificate from a new MAC machine on to the device D2(UDID of this device is already added to developer provisioning profile)?
3. If i had used adhoc provisioning profile and followed the same above steps will i be able to use instruments in Xcode ?

Thanks.

UPDATE 1
3. Answer - If i use adhoc distribution profile, i could not use instruments in xcode.

Comment: Do u want use New Mac Machine M2 to develop/debug/distribute the app with provision profile 1?

Comment: @Rupesh, I want to use the New MAC machine M2 to test the app.

Comment: Then you should export the private key,public key and developer certificate  into keychain of new Mac Machine M2 from M1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer1 - YES, provisioning profile will be installed successfully. 
Reason - Provisioning profile if included with the UDID of a device, it can be installed. No other dependancies. But in the Keychain access, you will get a warning telling that, valid identities are missing.

Answer2 - YES, we will be able to deploy the .ipa file on the Device D2. .ipa file internally has .app and the provisioning profile. We cannot deploy the app on device without developer certificate.

Answer3 - No, Distribution profile is for submitting apps in app store. Those apps cannot be debugged.

Adding to these answers, .dysm file helps developers to get more details while profiling. This .dysm file can be generated only with developer provisioning profile.

If anyone thinks my understanding is wrong in any aspect please add a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No that's not how things work

!) certificates must exist on every computer and on every device you want to test
2) On ad-hoc you must add the devices and then sent them some profiles for the phones.
3) then you archive and codesign app and send it wherever you want to.

OR you can use something like that https://testflightapp.com/

Comment: Is it mandatory to have the same developer certificate in MAC2 as in MAC 1. Is developer provisioning profile (updated with device 2 UDID) and latest .ipa file alone not sufficient to deploy it on device 2 ?